# Java - How to parse and process complex XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, process, config

I have a complex XML file which contains config information that will be parsed. An example:

```
<Rule>
<ID></ID>
<Center>
    <MethodCall>
        <Package></Package>
        <Method>
            <Pattern></Pattern>
        </Method>
        <Parameters>
            <ParametersCount>
                <Number>0,1-2,6+</Number>
            </ParametersCount>
            <Parameter>
                <Package></Package>
                <Position></Position>
                <Const>
                    <Number></Number>
                </Const>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
    </MethodCall>
</Center>
<Conditions>
    <Or>
        <Parameter>
            <Position>1</Position>
            <Package>com.test1</Package>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <Position>1</Position>
            <Package>com.test2</Package>
        </Parameter>
    </Or>
</Conditions>
</Rule>
```

It's config for AST analyzer. The code will be found by rules inside `center` tag, by later it will be parsed by `conditions` rules. By how to process it? I have two ideas:

1) Make a lot of classes for each tag (parameter, package, method and etc) and later read the rules inside those object and process it in my program.

2) Use Element and parse XML rules while processing the code.

UPD: I will clarify my needs. Just imagine that you have a lot of options that should be processed. In the case of example, MethodCall may not be contain some options and the parser should get the according object (so, if it doesn't contain Package, Method, any method call should be found), but after finding, it will be checked, if it satisfies conditions inside `Conditions` tag. The problem inside this. I don't know how to store this config info. Example, we got a method call, inside Conditions we have two Parameter options like in the code, and how to verify this? Create a list of conditions (but we need to have a linked list, because we have logical operators like Not, Or, And) like `List<Object>`, but those objects are objects of Parameter/ParametersCount/MethodName/PackageName/etc classes. Is that a good idea?

Comment: first link after googling [parse xml with java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: I know how to read it, I don't know how to store and process this complex config

Comment: Also do some research into xPath if you want to do any kind of querying

Comment: Do you have XSD file describing this request ? It would be simple to generate objects from XSD using JAXB to which you could bind XML as suggested in the answer bellow.

Comment: @user3360241, Yes, maybe this is I need, I will look into

Answer (score 1):

What is the anticipated size of the XML ? if it is not too large,  you can use [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) API to bind the whole XML hierarchy to related objects. This way you do not have to worry about creating/maintaining your object structure. Jaxb will generate it for you.
Once you parse the XML through jaxb(called unmarshalling), you have the object graph in memory, that you can traverse according to your program logic.